# Installing Pandas with Python 2.5 on Windows

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to get Pandas installed with Python 2.5 on a machine running Windows XP.

The installation seems to finish OK, but when I try

```
from pandas import *
```

I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<interactive input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "c:\python25\lib\site-packages\pandas-0.7.2-py2.5-win32.egg\pandas\__init__.py", line 24, in <module>
    from pandas.stats.api import *
  File "c:\python25\lib\site-packages\pandas-0.7.2-py2.5-win32.egg\pandas\stats\api.py", line 7, in <module>
    from pandas.stats.moments import *
  File "c:\python25\lib\site-packages\pandas-0.7.2-py2.5-win32.egg\pandas\stats\moments.py", line 388, in <module>
    rolling_max = _rolling_func(_tseries.roll_max, 'Moving maximum')
  File "c:\python25\lib\site-packages\pandas-0.7.2-py2.5-win32.egg\pandas\stats\moments.py", line 379, in _rolling_func
    def f(arg, window, min_periods=None, time_rule=None):
  File "C:\Python25\Lib\functools.py", line 35, in update_wrapper
    getattr(wrapper, attr).update(getattr(wrapped, attr))
AttributeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object has no attribute '__dict__'
```

As far as I can tell, I've got all of the dependencies installed correctly, and the problem is something to do with `functools.py`, which is part of the Python Standard Library(?).

Does anyone have any suggestions, please? Pandas is supposed to work with Python 2.5, so I assume it's a problem with my Python configuration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this the Python distro that came with ArcGIS or Python.org? As discussed on the mailing list this does not seem to be an issue with Python 2.5 per se but potentially your environment

Comment: Thanks Wes. For others, a few more details can be found [here](http://groups.google.com/group/pystatsmodels/browse_thread/thread/8c956f3a94ec3a06/c9fc539766e02235?pli=1). I tried installing Pandas with 2.5 on my laptop last night and it worked fine, so it's obviously a problem with this particular machine. I'll keep experimenting...